# Pandas: need to create dataframe for weekly search per event occurrence

Tags: pandas

If I have this events dataframe `df_e` below:

```
|------|------------|-------|
| group| event date | count |
| x123 | 2016-01-06 | 1     |
|      | 2016-01-08 | 10    |
|      | 2016-02-15 | 9     |
|      | 2016-05-22 | 6     |
|      | 2016-05-29 | 2     |
|      | 2016-05-31 | 6     |
|      | 2016-12-29 | 1     |
| x124 | 2016-01-01 | 1     |
...
```

and also know the `t0` which is the beginning of time (let's say for `x123` it's `2016-01-01`) and `tN` which is the end of experiment from another dataframe `df_s` (`2017-05-25`), then how can I create the dataframe `df_new` which should like this

```
|------|------------|---------------|--------|
| group| obs. weekly| lifetime, week| status |
| x123 | 2016-01-01 | 1             | 1      |
|      | 2016-01-08 | 0             | 0      |
|      | 2016-01-15 | 0             | 0      |
|      | 2016-01-22 | 1             | 1      |
|      | 2016-01-29 | 2             | 1      |
...
|      | 2017-05-18 | 1             | 1      |
|      | 2017-05-25 | 1             | 1      |
...
| x124 | 2017-05-18 | 1             | 1      |
| x124 | 2017-05-25 | 1             | 1      |
```

**Explanation**: take `t0` and generate rows until `tN` per **week** period. For each row `R`, search with that `group` if the event date falls within `R`, if True, then count how long in weeks it lives there, also set `status = 1` as alive, otherwise set `lifetime, status` columns for this `R` as 0, e.g. dead.

**Questions**:

1) How to generate dataframes per `group` given `t0` and `tN` values, e.g. generate [`group, obs. weekly, lifetime, status`] columns for `(tN - t0) / week` rows?

2) How to accomplish the construction of such `df_new` dataframe explained above?

I can begin with this so far =)

```
import pandas as pd

# 1. generate dataframes per group to get the boundary within `t0` and `tN` from df_s dataframe, where each dataframe has "group, obs, lifetime, status" columns X (tN - t0 / week) rows filled with 0 values.

df_all = pd.concat([df_group1, df_group2])

def do_that(R):
    found_event_row = df_e.iloc[[R.group]]

    # check if found_event_row['date'] falls into R['obs'] week
    # if True, then found how long it's there

df_new = df_all.apply(do_that)
```

Comment: @jezrael, maybe you can help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I get you but group one is not related to group two, right? if that's the case I think what you want is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_group1 = df_group1.set_index('event date') 
df_group1.index = pd.to_datetime(df_group1.index) #convert the index to datetime so you can 'resample'
df_group1['lifetime, week'] = df_group1.resample('1W').apply(lamda x: yourfuncion(x))
df_group1 = df_group1.reset_index()
df_group1['status']= df_group1.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['lifetime, week']>0 else 0)

#do the same with group2 and concat to create df_all
```

I'm not sure how you get 'lifetime, week' but all that's left is creating the function that generates it.